# React native overflow visible not working in android even after updated to RN 0.58.4

Tags: android, react-native

According to [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-0572) RN release , now on we can use `overflow:'visible'` in android . But still React Native Android clipping its Children view.  consider the below code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView,FlatList } from 'react-native';


type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  objectValues = {
    one: 'one',
    two: 'one',
    three: 'one',
    four: 'one',
    five: 'one',
    six: 'one',
    seven: 'one',
    eight: 'one',
    nine: 'one',
    ten: 'one',
    eleven: 'one'
  }
  listData=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
  renderBody(item, index) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
        <Text>{item}</Text>
        <View style={styles.overflowStyle} />
      </View>
    )
  }
  _renderList() {
    
        return (
          <FlatList
            bounces={false}
            style={[{ overflow: "visible" },{ zIndex:1},{ marginLeft:50 }, { marginRight: 50 },{ backgroundColor:'black'}]}
            numColumns={3}
            data={this.listData}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderBody(item, index)}
          />
        );
      }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollStyle}>
          <View>
            {Object.keys(this.objectValues)
              .map((key, index) => {
                console.log(key)
                return this._renderList()
              })}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',

  },

  innerContainer: {
    marginRight: 10,
    overflow:'visible',
    marginTop:10,
    height: 100,
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    zIndex:1
  },
  overflowStyle: {
    height: 20,
    width: 30,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    position: 'absolute',
    left: -20,
    top: 50,
    zIndex:10

  },
  scrollStyle:{
    overflow:'visible',
    zIndex:1,
    backgroundColor:'white'
  }
});
```

the code runs in iOS like this

[image]

But in Android its shows like this. The parent view clipping its child views. In my case parent is `ScrollView`

[image]

So my question is, are they fixed this issue or not? OR is there any proplem in my code ? please help

expo link   ::  https://snack.expo.io/ryZwe-mHN

Comment: **`overflow: visible` only works on iOS. On Android, all views will clip their children.** from the current documentation https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#overflow

Comment: But read here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/4af4da9089e20aa84bc5660bfb37763556442a4e

ScrollView always clipping children on Android *even when `overflow: visible` was specified*

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-0572 this release says that they are supporting overflow in android also

Comment: @Monte that is ear marked for `0.59.0-rc.1` so its not in `0.58.4`

Comment: Still broken for me on 0.61 even though it appears to been fixed already (https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.61/layout-props#overflow), can anyone verify?

Comment: Scrollview wasn't working for me, and overflow visible doesn't work, so I had to wrap my content in a View and set background colour as a trick to get it to render (use some background colour but set alpha to 0).

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing this issue, I was able to solve by providing transparent  background color to the parent view.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using overflow property inside a scroll view or flatlist, add this prop to your scrollview or flatlist

```
removeClippedSubviews(false)
```

On Android the default value is true which obstructs it from rendering extra content.

Comment: Doesn't work in code snack https://snack.expo.dev/@serena-yu/2c0207

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
I'm using Scrollview and want to handle some contents inside it, which are longer than screen width, but I also need to keep the Text fields inside the screen width.

So the issue was because I set `width: screenWidth` in `contentContainerStyle`
and when I remove `contentContainerStyle`, and add a view inside with that style, it working.

```
.....
        <ScrollView
          // contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollViewContent} //=> remove this
        >
          <View style={styles.scrollViewContent}> {/*Add this*/}
          {/*some contents*/}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>

.....
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollViewContent: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: screenWidth,
    overflow: 'visible',
  },

});
```